# Añadir con jquery el atributo onclick en enlaces dinamicamente

Tags: javascript, jquery

Mi codigo para añadir el atributo onclick no me esta funcionando y no me lo esta añadiendo, alguna idea del porque? Es una web especifica y que necesito añadirle este atributo con los códigos antiguos de analytics. Gracias.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('a[href="tel:911290000"]').attr("onclick","_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'telefono', 'llamada','movil']);");
    $('a[href="tel:687750000"]').attr("onclick","_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'telefono', 'llamada','movil']);");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: ¿Alguna pista de lo que te esta fallando? ¿En la consola no aparece ningún mensaje de error? La sintaxis esta bien así que lo mas probable es que no existe el enlace al que haces referencia.

Comment: La consola no me dice nada, puse un log despues de cada linea y me lo muestra bien

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('a[href="tel:911290000"]').click(function() {_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'telefono', 'llamada','movil']);
});
    $('a[href="tel:687750000"]').click(function() {_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'telefono', 'llamada','movil']);});
    });
</script>
```